# IwGame (Marmalade): Does CIwGameSprite support SVG? How?

Tags: c++, svg, marmalade

I have a small question about Marmalade IwGame engine.

Does the CIwGameSprite support SVG (I've read that yes it does)

If it does support SVG, how does it handle it,

Does it convert that Vector graphic to Pixel Graphics and cache it as an image then?

If it does not then how about the game performance? How does it handles animation, does it redraw the SVG each time?

How about scaling, if it does Caches images, Can I scale an SVG before scaling it?

Hopefully Someone can help

Thank you in advance

Ahmed

Comment: I'm reading about it, so maybe also if it is possible can we load an SVG into CIwGameImage? We might use libsvg to do that? If yes then can someone point out how to do this? I appreciate it.